# Meaning of . . . "fill up on a clean break"

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, technical

[(From *The Wrecker* by Robert Louis Stevenson and Lloyd Osbourne, Chapter XIII, published 1892)](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Wrecker_(Stevenson)/Chapter_13)

Passage 210

> Thence we turned our attention to the table, which stood spread, as if for a meal, with stout ship's crockery and the remains of food—a pot of marmalade, dregs of coffee in the mugs, unrecognisable remains of foods, bread, some toast, and a tin of condensed milk. The table-cloth, originally of a red colour, was stained a dark brown at the captain's end, apparently with coffee; at the other end, it had been folded back, and a pen and ink-pot stood on the bare table. Stools were here and there about the table, irregularly placed, as though the meal had been finished and the men smoking and chatting; and one of the stools lay on the floor, broken.
>
> “See! they were writing up the log,” said Nares, pointing to the ink-bottle. “Caught napping, as usual. I wonder if there ever was a captain yet, that lost a ship with his log-book up to date? He generally has about a month **to fill up on a clean break**, like Charles Dickens and his serial novels. What a regular, lime-juicer spread!” he added contemptuously. “Marmalade—and toast for the old man! Nasty, slovenly pigs!”

I read the sentence in question as follows: He...has about a month to fill up___on a clean break ( = *on a clean breakdown*???, or, maybe, *on a clean brake* (the ship ran aground :)???). What does *on a clean break* mean there? Thank you for helping.

Comment: I think the OP is misparsing the sentence; it's "he has a month to fill up", modified by "on a clear break", rather than "fill up on a clean break" being an idiomatic expression.

Comment: I think we would now say "catch up".

Comment: You have cross-posted this question: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/343032/meaning-of-fill-up-on-a-clean-break#comment660377_343032

Comment: @ Lambie: Not cross-posted - 'post'-posted on recommendation of our member TimR. Please have a look at your link once again.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

My guess:
the Captain is likely to be about a month behind writing the log, so that when he has a block of free time (a clean break) he can write the missing parts of (fill up) the log.

Comment: Yes, well, it is all a guessing game.